# Check all li if one has class active then only parent ul addclass

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I tried with my code but it's adding `class="in"` not only active parents but also other parents too. I want to add class only for active parent only not others.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".left_menu .nav-second-level li").each(function() {
    if ($('.left_menu .nav-second-level li').hasClass('active')) {
      $(this).parents('.left_menu .nav-second-level').addClass('in');
    } else {
      $(this).parents('.left_menu .nav-second-level').removeClass('in');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
  background-color: red;
}
.in {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
  <li class="left_menu">
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i> 
      <span class="nav-label">Employee</span>
      <span class="fa arrow"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
      <li class="">
        <a href="">create account</a>
      </li>
      <li class="">
        <a href="">role set</a>
      </li>
      <li class="active">
        <a href="">capability set</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="left_menu">
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>
      <span class="nav-label">Department</span>
      <span class="fa arrow"></span>
    </a>

    <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
      <li class="">
        <a href="">Add department</a>
      </li>
      <li class="">
        <a href="">Vew Deparment</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: for these things, you need to fiddle your problem, for beter visualization.

Comment: Why are you asking for a fiddle when there's a fully working snippet in the question showing the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use `each` you can do it easily like following.

```
$('.left_menu .nav-second-level li').parent().removeClass('in')
$('.left_menu .nav-second-level li.active').parent().addClass('in')
```

**Full Snippet**

```js
$('.left_menu .nav-second-level li').parent().removeClass('in')
 $('.left_menu .nav-second-level li.active').parent().addClass('in')
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
  background-color: red;
}
.in {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
  <li class="left_menu">
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i> 
      <span class="nav-label">Employee</span>
      <span class="fa arrow"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
      <li class="">
        <a href="">create account</a>
      </li>
      <li class="">
        <a href="">role set</a>
      </li>
      <li class="active">
        <a href="">capability set</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="left_menu">
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>
      <span class="nav-label">Department</span>
      <span class="fa arrow"></span>
    </a>

    <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
      <li class="">
        <a href="">Add department</a>
      </li>
      <li class="">
        <a href="">Vew Deparment</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the `each` handler you need to use the `this` reference to the current element being iterated over. Your current code doesn't work as you're selecting all the `li` elements and checking if *any* of them has an `active` class. You can also use `toggleClass` with the boolean state flag to reduce your code. Try this:

```
$(".left_menu .nav-second-level li").each(function() {
    $(this).parents('.left_menu .nav-second-level').toggleClass('in', $(this).hasClass('active'));
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $(".left_menu .nav-second-level li").each(function() {
    $(this).parents('.left_menu .nav-second-level').toggleClass('in', $(this).hasClass('active'));
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
  background-color: red;
}
.in {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
  <li class="left_menu">
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i> 
      <span class="nav-label">Employee</span>
      <span class="fa arrow"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
      <li class="">
        <a href="">create account</a>
      </li>
      <li class="">
        <a href="">role set</a>
      </li>
      <li class="active">
        <a href="">capability set</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="left_menu">
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>
      <span class="nav-label">Department</span>
      <span class="fa arrow"></span>
    </a>

    <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
      <li class="">
        <a href="">Add department</a>
      </li>
      <li class="">
        <a href="">Vew Deparment</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is inside the .each, you're fetching all those elements again. This means you'll always target all elements. What you want to do is use the CURRENT element to check if it .hasClass, just like you did inside the if and else.

```
 $(function() {
     $(".left_menu .nav-second-level li").each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
      $(this).parents('.left_menu .nav-second-level').addClass('in');
    } else {
      $(this).parents('.left_menu .nav-second-level').removeClass('in');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#side-menu").find(".active").addClass("in");
$("#side-menu").find(".active").parent().addClass("in");
```

use the above code for your requirement achievement.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(function() {

    $(".left_menu .nav-second-level li").each(function() {
       if ( $(this).hasClass('active') ) { 
          $(this).parent().addClass('in'); 
       }  else {
          $(this).parent().removeClass('in');
       }
    });
});
```